# Multiple function apps on a single app plan

Tags: azure, azure-functions

When you create a new function app you can choose an AppPlan. If you choose an EP3 AppPlan as an example it says "estimated cost 200 dollars". If I create 3 different function apps all on the same AppPlan. Will it then be 200x3 dollars or do you pay pr AppPlan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to Azure functions with App Service Plan, you don’t get to pay for the number of executions, execution time, and memory used. Instead, you pay for the cost of the VM instance that you allocate. So, in this case, you will be charged based on the VM (does not matter how many functions you use). However, the recommended practice is to stick with the consumption plan

Comment: Thanks for your reply - appreciated. We are also using consumption plans. But we have some functions that needs to run for longer than 5 minutes. We know it is best practices to only have short running executions, but when working with the SharePoint API it is not always an option due to the nature of SharePoint and very large lists and throttles.